# How to create the "less read" link button to display less of the text

Tags: jquery

I need help...
I have posts with some text 
      "blablablabalbalbalablala... Read More" 
When I click on Read more I see whole post,
with this code

```
$(function(){ 
 $('.news').each(function(event){ 
    var max_length = 450; 
    if($(this).html().length > max_length){ 
            var short_content   = $(this).html().substr(0,max_length); 
            var long_content    = $(this).html().substr(max_length);
    $(this).html(short_content+'<a href="#" class="read_more" style="float:right; margin:20px 40px 0 0;"><br/>Read More</a>'+ '<span class="more_text" style="display:none;">'+long_content); 
    $(this).find('a.read_more').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parents('.news').find('.more_text').show(); 
    });  
    }
    }); 
});
```

That works fine but,
How to add Read less button so when I click on it I will be back in the previous position...?

New here so sorry...
Ok I have

```
<div class="news"> some text some text some text some text some text some text </div>
```

and read more is inside my jquery code... so I don't know how to add Read Less...?
:)

Comment: please provide your html elements which are used by .news and a.read_more , Read More and Read less button

Comment: Ok I have...
<div class="news"> some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</div>

and read more is inside jquery...
so I don't know how to add Read Less

Comment: edit question when providing additional code, not comment block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to modify your code a little, have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/hqPy6/3/)

I've added another button (Read Less) that changes the innerHTML of the .news tag to the short_content value

```
$('a.read_less').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(me).html(short_content);
                $(this).hide();
                $('a.read_more').show();
});
```

Comment: I've tinkered some more with the code. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/hqPy6/3/)'s the updated fiddle.

Comment: works great, just have little problem...when I add links inside text...they don't show as links, they showing as text...also is happening when I add <p> tag! :(

Comment: links showing as text...you may have missed the href attribute. Also if you want to have html tags inside the span that is being created in the each function, you may want to use .html() instead of .text()