# how to create read more with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need create read more function in jQuery, for example when character length is 30 show text, but when character is more, show only 30 character.

```
$('.dep_buttons').mouseover(function(){
    // please insert script here
    $(this).stop().animate({height:"100px"},150); // when character > 30 need this
    $(".dep_buttons").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:"30px"},150);
    });
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305326/how-to-create-the-less-read-link-button-to-display-less-of-the-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($('your class').text().length() > 30) {});
```

you need this script

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `length` of your `html element` like,

```
$('.dep_buttons').mouseover(function(){
    if($('.dep_buttons').text().length > 30) { //if length of text is > 30 => animate
        $(this).stop().animate({height:"100px"},150);
    }
});
$(".dep_buttons").mouseout(function(){
    if($('.dep_buttons').text().length > 30) {
       $(this).stop().animate({height:"30px"},150);
    }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VDW9W/)

**Updated** use `$(this).text()` in place of `$('.dep_buttons').text()` like,

```
$('.dep_buttons').mouseover(function () {
    //// $(this).text()
    if ($(this).text().length > 30) { //if length of text is > 30 => animate
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: "100px"
        }, 150);
    }
});
$(".dep_buttons").mouseout(function () {
    if ($(this).text().length > 30) {// $(this).text()
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: "30px"
        }, 150);
    }
});
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VDW9W/1/)

Comment: I need `(this)` element where add it?

Comment: I need this function for meny elements

Comment: @valkharitonashvili see my `updated answer` and `demo`.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="comment more">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
    quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.
    Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
    blandit id luctus felis convallis.
    Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
    Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.
</div>
<div class="comment more">
    Duis nisl nibh, egestas at fermentum at, viverra et purus.
    Maecenas lobortis odio id sapien facilisis elementum.
    Curabitur et magna justo, et gravida augue.
    Sed tristique pellentesque arcu quis tempor.
</div>
<div class="comment more">
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin blandit nunc sed sem dictum id feugiat quam blandit.
    Donec nec sem sed arcu interdum commodo ac ac diam. Donec consequat semper rutrum.
    Vestibulum et mauris elit. Vestibulum mauris lacus, ultricies.
</div>
```

CSS

```
a {
    color: #0254EB
}
a:visited {
    color: #0254EB
}
a.morelink {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.comment {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 100;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/show-more-link-shortened-content/

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of not spoon feeding you the answer, I'll give you these links:

[`String.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length), [`String.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Check the length of the string. If it is greater than 30, get the substring that contains the first 30 characters.

Comment: please add your script :)

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScrit `.length` function you can count your string.

I didn't try it out but it can look like this:

```
if(foo.length > 30) {
'do something'
}
else {
'do something'
}
```

Comment: I try this but not work :(. I need check a tag's text length

`<a class="dep_buttons" href="#">somethig text</a>`

Comment: if($('.deep_buttons').text().length() > 30) {... i think so it have to look like. i can try is out later